# What is the use of __attribute__ (format) in C to define a function?

Tags: c, gcc

I came across this line of code in a C project, and I did not understand it.

```
#define FMT_CHK(fmt, args)  __attribute__ ((format (printf, fmt, args)))
```

The GNU website does not explain it clearly (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)

What is the purpose of `__attribute__ ((format ())` and how should it be used?

Comment: What part do you want help with?  The manual seems quite clear to me, it even provides an example of how to use it, and I don't want to copy and paste the manual into an answer here.

Comment: what is fmt and args exactly? At some examples, fmt is 1 or 2, args is 2 or 3. fmt means "the number of the "format string" parameter" and args means "the number of the first variadic parameter." I didnt understand that, and how it will be used.

Comment: This is very well explained in the gcc documentation. But understanding does require some knowledge about C basics. If you don't understand, you should learn these basics - no offence.

Comment: The macro expands to an attribute declaration, and that attribute must be associated with a function.  The `fmt` and `args` parameters to the macro are indices into the argument list of that function, indicating the position of the format string and of the first argument to check against the format, respectively.

Comment: Note also that the whole `__attribute__` thing is a GCC extension, not part of standard C.  If you never learn or use it then you probably won't be much impaired.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, the `fmt` and `args` parameters just tell you which parameter has the format, and which parameter has the arguments.

```
void myprintf(const char *fmt, ...);
//            ^^ fmt = arg#1
//                             ^^ args = arg#2...
```

So in this case, the correct attribute is:

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))
```

If you have a longer function declaration...

```
void myprintf(obj *x, const char *fmt, int level, ...)
//                    ^^ format: arg#2
//                                                ^^ args: arg#4...
    __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 4)));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a header `stderr.h`, which amongst other things contains the stanza:

```
#if !defined(PRINTFLIKE)
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define PRINTFLIKE(n,m) __attribute__((format(printf,n,m)))
#else
#define PRINTFLIKE(n,m) /* If only */
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
#endif /* PRINTFLIKE */
```

and also contains declarations such as:

```
extern NORETURN void err_abort(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2);
extern NORETURN void err_error(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2);
extern NORETURN void err_error1(const char *s1);
extern NORETURN void err_error2(const char *s1, const char *s2);
extern NORETURN void err_help(const char *use_str, const char *hlp_str);
extern NORETURN void err_helplist(const char *use_str, const char * const *help_list);
extern NORETURN void err_internal(const char *function, const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(2,3);
extern NORETURN void err_syserr(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2);
extern NORETURN void err_syserr1(const char *s1);
extern NORETURN void err_syserr2(const char *s1, const char *s2);
extern NORETURN void err_syserror(int errnum, const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(2,3);

extern void err_logmsg(FILE *fp, int flags, int estat, const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(4,5);
extern void err_print(int flags, int estat, const char *format, va_list args);
extern void err_printversion(const char *program, const char *verinfo);
extern void err_remark(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2);
extern void err_remark1(const char *s1);
extern void err_remark2(const char *s1, const char *s2);
extern void err_report(int flags, int estat, const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(3,4);
extern void err_sysrem(const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(1,2);
extern void err_sysrem1(const char *s1);
extern void err_sysrem2(const char *s1, const char *s2);
extern void err_sysremark(int errnum, const char *format, ...) PRINTFLIKE(2,3);
```

The `NORETURN` is another piece of conditional compilation, indicating that these functions do not return once called.  The testing is slightly more complex as Standard C (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) has a built-in mechanism — `_Noreturn` — that can be used with compilers that support C11.

```
#if !defined(NORETURN)
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
#define NORETURN      _Noreturn
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define NORETURN      __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
#define NORETURN      /* If only */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ || __GNUC__ */
#endif /* NORETURN */
```

Note how the mechanism keeps out of the way when the compiler does not claim to be GCC (`__GNUC__`).  Unless you're willing to tie yourself exclusively to GCC, protective code along these lines is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

quote from gcc page:

> The format attribute specifies that a function takes printf, scanf, strftime or strfmon style arguments that should be type-checked against a format string.

like `__attribute__ ((format (printf, format_param, arg_list))`

gcc will help you check `arg_list` type is corresponding to `format_param` during compile time.